# Microsoft teams issue on below request with Active cards post request

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am seeing the issue as " 400 Bad Request: [Summary or Text is required.]" Any one got the solution on this

tried same request in postman even there also i see same issue as 400 bad request.

400 Bad Request: [Summary or Text is required.]

{
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"version": "1.2",
"body": [
{
"type": "ColumnSet",
"columns": [
{
"type": "Column",
"items": [
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"weight": "Bolder",
"text": "TItle1",
"separator": true
},
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"separator": true,
"text": "body1"
},
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"separator": true,
"text": "body4"
}
],
"width": "stretch",
"style": "accent"
},
{
"type": "Column",
"items": [
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"weight": "Bolder",
"text": "title2"
},
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"separator": true,
"text": "body2"
},
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"separator": true,
"text": "body5"
}
],
"width": "stretch",
"style": "good"
},
{
"type": "Column",
"items": [
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"weight": "Bolder",
"text": "title3"
},
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"separator": true,
"text": "body3"
},
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"separator": true,
"text": "body6"
}
],
"width": "stretch",
"style": "warning"
}
]
}
]
}

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you.

Comment: Have you tried a super simple post to see if it works at all?

Answer (score 5):

I have reproduced the same schema that has been provided in the question. This schema works absolutely fine at my end.

If you're still facing the problem, try to change the Adaptive card version from 1.2 to 1.0 and recheck it; this should resolve your issue.